# Fredholm alternative interpretation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $T \in \mathcal{K}(E)$, that is, $T$ is a compact operator in the Banach space $E$. Consider $N(T)=\{x \in E: Tx=0\}$ and $R(T)=\{y \in E:y=Tx 
 ~(\exists x \in E)\}$.

In Brézis book we have the following result:

**Theorem 6.6 (Fredholm Alternative)** Let $T \in \mathcal{K}(E).$ Then

a) $N(I-T)$ is finite dimensional,

b) $R(I-T)$ is closed, and more precisely $R(I-T)=N(I-T^*)^\perp$,

c) $N(I-T)=\{0\} \Leftrightarrow R(I-T)=E$,

d) $\dim N(I-T)=\dim N(I-T^*)$.

After the theorem the author says:

*Remark 4*: The Fredholm alternative deals with the solvability of the equation
$u − T u = f$. It says that

$\bullet $ *either* for every $f \in E$ the equation $u − T u = f$ has a unique solution,

$\bullet $ *or* the homogeneous equation $u−T u = 0$ admits $n$ linearly independent solutions,
and in this case, the inhomogeneous equation $u−T u = f$ is solvable if and only
if $f$ satisfies $n$ orthogonality conditions, i.e., $N(I-T^*)^\perp$.

**My question:** I would like to know how to interpret the second part of the Remark 4.

For example, in the first part, if for every $f \in E$ the equation $u − T u = f$ has a unique solution, then the only solution for $u-Tu=0$ is $u=0$. Therefore, $N(I-T)=\{0\}$. If this is not the case, then there exists $f \in E$ such that $u-Tu=f$ has more than one solution, for example, $u_1\neq  u_2$. Therefore, $u_1-u_2 \neq 0$ and $u_1-u_2 \in N(I-T)$, that is, $N(I-T) \neq \{0\}$.

I still can't understand how this second part is justified (especially the bold part):

*or* the homogeneous equation $u−T u = 0$ admits $n$ linearly independent solutions,
**and in this case**, the inhomogeneous equation $u−T u = f$ is solvable if and only
if $f$ satisfies $n$ orthogonality conditions, i.e., $N(I-T^*)^\perp$.

Comment: Define $N,R$. Do you mean null space and range? You can render `\ker` in MathJax to avoid confusion, and you can put `\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{Im}}` at the start of your text in order to write the image as well, which is more standard notation

Comment: @FShrike: with "Fredholm Alternative" in the title and "Functional Analysis" as a tag, there is absolutely no confusion about what $N$ and $R$ are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N(I-T)\ne\{0\}$, then by the theorem you know that $n=\dim(I-T)<\infty$. So there are $n$ linearly independent solutions $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ to the homogeneous problem.

And $f$ is a solution of the full problem if and only if $f\in R(I-T)=N(I-T^*)^\perp$. That is, $f$ is a solution if and only if $f$ is orthogonal to each of $g_1,\ldots,g_n$; these are the "$n$ orthogonality conditions".

Comment: What is confusing me is the phrase **and in this case $\dots$**. It seems to me that the equation $u-Tu=f$ has a solution if and only if $f \in N(I-T^*)^\perp$ always (because $R(I-T)=N(I-T^*)^\perp$), and not just in the case where $N(I-T) \neq \{0\}$. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yes. But when $n\geq1$ you get to write actual equations that the solution has to satisfy. The condition "$f$ is in the range of $I-T$ gives you nothing practical; while the condition "$f$ is orthogonal to these $n$ elements" gives you concrete equations that you can write.

Comment: Thank you! There is a typo in the answer, "amd", could you fix it?

Comment: Done, thanks. $ $

Comment: Hi Martin Argerami, do you know a example of a compact operator in a infinite dimensional Banach space satisfying the **second case** of the Fredholm alternative and how to solve this equation by using the $n$ orthogonality conditions?

Comment: Ther kernel of $I-T$ are the eigenvectors of $T$ with eigenvalue 1. So make up a compact operator with $n$-dimensional eigenspace for the eigenvalue 1 and you are done. As for solving, the orthogonality conditions will not likely help you solve the equation; they are a necessary and sufficient condition on $f$ for a solution $u$ to exist.

Comment: I thought more about it but still haven't come up with an compact operator with an eigenspace of dimension $n$. The example that comes to my mind is the operator $T:\ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ given by $Tu=(\alpha_1u_1,\alpha_2 u_2, \dots)$ where $(\alpha_j)$ is a strictly decreasing sequence with $\alpha_1=1$. Then, $\dim E_1=1$.

Comment: I think I can adapt this example by taking $\alpha=(1,\dots,1,\alpha_{n+1},\dots)$ with $\alpha_{n+1}<1$ and $(\alpha_{j})$ strictly decreasing for $j \geq n+1$. Then, $\dim N(T-I)=n$.

Comment: It doesn't have to be strictly decreasing. You could have also taken $\alpha_{n+k}=0$ for all $k$. That is, an orthogonal projection onto a subspace of dimension $n$ is a compact operator with $1$ as an eigenvalue of multiplicity $n$.

Answer (score 3):

A way to understand what mean these conditions is to consider the finite dimensional case, ie you take a square matrix $A$ of size $n$ for $I-T$ and try to solve $AX=F$. Two cases:

- either $AX=B$ has an unique solution,
- or $A$ has rank $m<n$ thus solving $AX=0$ will give $m-n$ independent vectors. Now as the range of $A$ is not all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if you consider a $B\in \mathbb{R}^n$ there will be a solution only if it is in the orthogonal of the space span by the $m-n$ Vectors.
  A simple example is to solve for
  $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix}.$$
  $A$ has rank $1$ and $AX=0$ is spanned by $e_1=(1,-1,0)$ and $e_2=(1,0,-1)$,for instance. $AX=B$ has a solution if $B\cdot e_i=0$ for $i=1,2$ which gives $b1=b2=b3$. Hope that helps!